# How to fix: "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main"?

Tags: java, android, crash

I am developing an application, and every time I run it, my app crashes. When I look in **Stack trace** I receive this message.

---

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fast.com, PID: 17032
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fast.com/fast.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at fast.com.MainActivity$1.<init>(MainActivity.java:30)
        at fast.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) emphasized text
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

When I look to **Stack Trace** I understand nothing. If you have some time please answer because I really need it.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-read-and-understand-a-java-stacktrace

Comment: In particular there you will want to look at the "Caused by" line. Read the full line itself, it says what the error is. Then read the next line, it tells you where it happened. If that still does not make sense, please post your `MainActivity` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` says your `FirebaseAuth` is null so you can not call  `getCurrentUser` on it.

Check your `MainActivity.java` line 29, 30.

Comment: I checked my MainActivity.java lin e29, 30 and I don't see any error

Comment: mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()

Comment: @Seyinator Please post your MainActivity class (fast.com.MainActivity) for further analysis.

Comment: please can you look at source code I posted just now

Comment: @Seyinator You never assign a value to `mFirebaseAuth` so it is null. When you call `FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` an NPE(NullPointerException ) will be thrown out. PS: You should edit the question instead of adding an answer

Comment: it helped me a lot! I solved that problem! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Here is MainActivity

```
package fast.com;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
Button haveAccountButton, signUpButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    haveAccountButton = findViewById(R.id.haveAccountButton);

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
             if (mFirebaseUser != null ){
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're logged in", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                 startActivity(i);
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Login", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }
    };

    haveAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intToSignUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intToSignUp);
        }
    });

}




}
```

Comment: There is no proper explanation